# LibreOffice Interior.ColorIndex hides cell borders

Tags: libreoffice

I've ported an Excel spreadsheet to LibreOffice 7.4 (on Windows).

The spreadsheet uses VBA / StarBasic to set the background color to yellow on 'warning' conditions, then sets the background color to zero when the condition is cleared:

```
ws.Rows(rErrCell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
...
ws.Rows(rErrCell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
```

On LibreOffice, this clears the borders. Is there anyway to stop this happening? Or how do I redraw the borders after this has happened?

(I've tried setting Interior.pattern to zero, and restoring the border.LineStyle, but neither seem to have any effect. In the GUI, I can set the 'color' to None.)

Answer (score 0):

In excel, perhaps for some ancient backward compatibility reason, setting the color index to zero actually sets the color index and pattern to xlNone (which is a non-zero value)

In libreoffice, this does not work. But it is possible to explicitly set the color index to xlNone

There may also be a way to draw borders when the color index is not xlNone, but I haven't found it and don't need to know.